# Flask -The requested url is not found

Tags: python, flask

I am getting the error that "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." when I click on register button. The app is running fine initially, but when I click on the register button only, I am getting this error.

I have included the following files in the project:

/env,/template,/index.html, /success.html, /app.py

Code in the app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    name = request.args.get("name", "world")
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


@app.route("/register", methods=["POST"])
def register():
    name = request.form.get("name")
    dorm = request.form.get("dorm")
    if not name or not dorm:
        return "failure"
    return render_template("success.html")
```

Comment: Just move the `if` block to the bottom under the `register` definition.

Comment: Nope.. same error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect it to show a response when you never assigned one,
POST method is on posting a form, GET method is for the response, which is the one you want to achieve in here.

simply add at the bottom of your script

```js
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET"])
def viewRegister():
    ...
```

or so it should be, I work with django and node Im pretty sure its the same in flask.

> NOTE: you should always run this at the bottom of your script.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> To POST something via input you should go to any GET method route and add within it a form just like this.

```
<form action="/register" method="POST">
    <input name=''>
    <button type='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: I want to post a name through input

Comment: Yep, as advised i have added                                                     if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)